# ¿Cómo puedo acceder al contenido de un arreglo? error UNDEFINED

Tags: javascript

EDIT.

En la primera promise recorró un array y obtengo los elemento que quiero guardar en el array que denominé arregloaux

Luego en la segunda promise imprimo el arregloaux me arroja los resultados pero al momento de querer trabajar con ellos es donde tengo problemas

```
function resolveAfter3Seconds() {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
 setTimeout(() => {

   console.log("array nuevo "+ arregloaux); 
   //{ nombre: Esperanza Canales, id: 25, longitud: 1.1 km, tiempo:3 min }
   const jsonPrimerObjeto = JSON.Parse(arregloaux[0]); 
   console.log("array nuevo 2: "+ jsonPrimerObjeto); 
   const id = jsonPrimerObjeto.id;
   const nombre = jsonPrimerObjeto.nombre;
   const tiempo = jsonPrimerObjeto.tiempo;
   console.log("id: "+id,+"nombre: "+ nombre,+"tiempo: "+  tiempo);
   // undefined
   resolve('resolved 3');
     }, 3000);
     });
}
```

PREGUNTA INICIAL.

Tengo un array el cual le paso un objeto mediante un push
    al momento de hacer console.log veo lo siguiente:

```
   console.log(arreglo[min_pos]);
  // { nombre: Esperanza Canales, id: 25, longitud: 0.7 km, tiempo:2 min }

  var arregloaux = new Array();
  arregloaux.push(arreglo[min_pos]);

  console.log("array nuevo "+ arregloaux);
  //  array nuevo { nombre: Esperanza Canales, id: 25, longitud: 1.1 km, tiempo:3 min }
  var id  = arregloaux[0].id;
  // undefined
```

Como puedo acceder al id del arreglo???

Comment: `var id  = arregloaux[0].id;` no uses JSON.stringify

Comment: Una pregunta amiga @PaulaAlvarez, podrias editar un momento la pregunta y mostrar que es lo que contiene arreglo[min_pos], es decir, si ya contiene un objeto json?, porque si contiene un objeto json en si ya parseado (no una cadena de texto), entonces Lobos tiene razon.

Comment: lo imprimiré así console.log(arreglo[min_pos]) y lo editaré

Comment: Que tal?, acabo de editar mi respuesta, tal vez sirva de algo ahora... espero que si...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pueden ser dos problemas... ya sea uno o el otro, a mi se me ocurre que uno de ellos puede ser que en otra parte del codigo estes intentando usar las variables que creaste dentro de la promise de manera directa antes de que incluso la promise llegue a resolverse, en cuyo caso es por eso que arroja undefined...

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que segun veo en tu codigo, `arregloaux` ya tiene directamente un objeto `json`:

```
console.log("array nuevo "+ arregloaux); 
//{ nombre: Esperanza Canales, id: 25, longitud: 1.1 km, tiempo:3 min }
```

asi que enrealidad no necesitamos el codigo como lo habia puesto anteriormente, por lo que tu **codigo original** realmente quedaria asi:

```js
//Solo un ejemplo, en tu codigo seguro tendras esto diferente
const arreglo = [{nombre: "Esperanza Canales", id: 25, longitud: "0.7 km", tiempo: "2 min"}];
const min_pos = 0;

console.log(arreglo[min_pos]);
// { nombre: Esperanza Canales, id: 25, longitud: 0.7 km, tiempo:2 min }

var arregloaux = new Array();
arregloaux.push(arreglo[min_pos]);

console.log("array nuevo "+ arregloaux);

//Aqui tenias esto, no necesitas usar JSON.stringify para acceder a id
//var id  = JSON.stringify(arregloaux[0].id);

//Queda esta parte asi:
var id  = arregloaux[0].id;
```

Entonces la parte completa que tienes ahora, enrealidad sospecho que tendra entonces que pasar de ser esto:

```
function resolveAfter3Seconds() {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
 setTimeout(() => {

   console.log("array nuevo "+ arregloaux); 
   //{ nombre: Esperanza Canales, id: 25, longitud: 1.1 km, tiempo:3 min }
   const jsonPrimerObjeto = JSON.Parse(arregloaux[0]); 
   console.log("array nuevo 2: "+ jsonPrimerObjeto); 
   const id = jsonPrimerObjeto.id;
   const nombre = jsonPrimerObjeto.nombre;
   const tiempo = jsonPrimerObjeto.tiempo;
   console.log("id: "+id,+"nombre: "+ nombre,+"tiempo: "+  tiempo);
   // undefined
   resolve('resolved 3');
     }, 3000);
     });
}
```

a esto:

```js
function resolveAfter3Seconds() {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        
       //Solo un ejemplo, en tu codigo seguro tendras esto diferente
       const arreglo = [{nombre: "Esperanza Canales", id: 25, longitud: "0.7 km", tiempo: "2 min"}];
       const min_pos = 0;
       
       var arregloaux = new Array();
       arregloaux.push(arreglo[min_pos]);

       const id = arregloaux[0].id;
       const nombre = arregloaux[0].nombre;
       const tiempo = arregloaux[0].tiempo;
       
       resolve(arregloaux);
     }, 3000);
  });
}

/*
  Nota no intentes usar aqui directamente arregloaux ni las variables declaradas dentro de
  resolveAfter3Seconds porque el resultado sera undefined siempre, es decir:
*/

//console.log(arregloaux);           undefined
//console.log(id, nombre, tiempo);   undefined

//No puedes usar estas variables.

resolveAfter3Seconds().then(data =>{
  
  //Solo podras usar alguna data que hayas devuelvo en el resolve de la promise aqui dentro
  //En este caso recuerda que devolvimos arregloaux en el resolve. las otras variables
  //Declaradas dentro de resolveAfter3Seconds no existiran o guardaran undefined.
  //asi que no intentes usarlas nisiquiera.
  console.log(data);

}).catch(e =>{
  console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: pero en su ejemplo no tiene comillas las palabras "nombre":" Esperanza Canales", como tiene que hacer para que funcione?

Comment: Cierto, editado para poder explicar del porque se formateo asi al op, gracias por la recomendacion x-rw! :3

Comment: Gracias por responder, aun persiste el problema creo que es algo de la asincronía de mi código

Comment: Asincronia??, usas alguna promise o funcion asincrona o llamas a algo asincrono en alguna parte??, porfavor si es asi considera editar la pregunta y poner esa parte... puesto que si es asi, habrá que hacer algunos ajustes...

Comment: Muchas gracias @Riven !!